# ESP32 stops responding after a week

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I'm using a ESP32 (NodeMCU-ESP32 ESP32 DEVKITV1) to track the value of a temperature sensor. Everything seems to be working fine initially, I can access the webpage (`WebServer.h`) via the IP address and or via the mDNS (`ESPmDNS.h`) hostname. However, after about a week it stops responding. I can't access it using either method.

I tried setting up a watchdog timer for 240 seconds using `esp_task_wdt.h`. I initialise this in `setup()` with

```
esp_task_wdt_init(240, true);
esp_task_wdt_add(NULL);
```

and then call `esp_task_wdt_reset()` in every iteration of my loop (which is where I call `server.handleClient()`, for instance). However, this doesn't change anything. It still fails after about a week.

I also tried restarting the ESP every day by adding

```
unsigned long current_millis = millis();
if (current_millis > 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
{
    esp_restart();
}
```

to my loop, but it continues to fail after about a week. However, if I press the hardware reset button on the board it will instantly start working again (for another week).

What could be going wrong? While it would be nice to know why it's failing at all, I would be happy with any solution that explains why both my attempts at dealing with the problem failed.

Comment: Most likely you are running out of some resource, like free memory, network buffers, file handles, etc. Monitor the application and see what you are using and forgetting to close or free.

Comment: DHCP or static IP?

Comment: @Juraj I'm using DHCP.

Comment: @stark yes, I expect so. The problem is that I have no way of monitoring resource usage for an entire week. Also, that still doesn't explain why neither the watchdog timer nor frequent restarts solve the problem.

Comment: You can wire up a spare ESP32 or ESP8266 (or whatever CPU you have lying around) to record the output from TX. It's also easy to have an ESP32 or ESP8266 log it to a server online. Unfortunately there are plenty of failure modes that a watchdog timer won't catch; it's only useful for code that fails by locking up in a loop. Frequent restarts not solving the problem is curious though. Following up on @Juraj's question, perhaps try configuring it with a static IP (after you make sure the IP address is reserved on your router).

Comment: Also try pinging it before and after it fails... if it still responds to ping after a failure, that's an interesting data point. And if you can, check your router/wifi to see if it's still connected and active on the network.

Comment: @romkey thanks for the suggestions. The ping does work before the failure and doesn't afterwards. I may try logging to a server, that makes sense. Can you expand on the "failure modes that a watchdog timer won't catch"? I thought the whole point of a watchdog timer was that it was the final option for dealing with problems and should always work. Or is there a lower level hardware watchdog timer in some CPUs which would fit this understanding?

Comment: the ping and wdt suggest your task is still running and resetting wdt but the network has failed. Try sending ping every few seconds and see if xmit also stops or just recv. If only recv then likely resources, if xmit also then maybe interface is down. periodically log number of outstanding requests

Comment: @David - the WDT only helps when the CPU gets stuck in a loop. It's a guard against a particular class of failures. There exists no guard against all classes of failures. Consider a well-written program which stops working because it runs out of memory... In `loop()` it tries to allocate something, fails, and returns... then tries again... fails... and returns. WDT won't help with this situation at all.

Comment: @romkey I understood that the WDT basically created a periodic timer. If this timer finished counting down, it triggered the ISR, which, by default, calls `ESP.restart()`. Surely it doesn't matter if memory overflows or anything else since the timer will always trigger and a restart should clear any memory problems?

Comment: @David yes that's basically what it does. But that only catches a certain category of bugs - ones where your code is accidentally stuck in an infinite loop. There are many other kinds of problems that can break a program without it being stuck in an infinite loop. And in Arduino code, when `loop()` returns, the watchdog is automatically reset. So in the example I wrote before, the program would fail but the watchdog timer wouldn't fire.

Comment: @romkey that makes more sense, I hadn't realised it would reset the watchdog when `loop()` exited. Thanks for your help (and patience!). I'll update when it next goes down and I can test a few other things.

Comment: Good luck with it!

Comment: Have you checked whether the code actually stops running or you are just losing the WiFi connectivity.  The problem may have nothing to do with the code but just some issue with your WiFi access point denying access to the ESP32 for whatever reason.
I would put some serial.prints in the loop so you can see if it is still running by connecting a laptop or something.  Even simpler just add an LED that flashes in the main loop so at a glance you can see if it is still running.
The other thing I would try is simply to use a different WiFi access point and see if the same happens.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Christian, the LED could have helped a lot. Connecting a laptop would have been complex given how the ESP was connected.

Comment: @romkey I believe I have found the original problem, but my question was specifically why my mitigation techniques weren't working. I think my solution explains why rebooting every night didn't work, but if you would add an answer explaining what you said about the watchdog timer (including resetting when `loop` exits), I think that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching, I think I finally identified the original problem (though something may have reset the ESP more recently). I'm posting this since similar code appears on various websites.

The problem was directly to do with the code I was using for mDNS. Basically, if mDNS failed to initialise I restarted the ESP. This appears to have caused some problem after a few days and then left the ESP in a boot loop. Should have been obvious, but I missed it.

I think this also explains why restarting every night didn't solve the problem, since this could also trigger the boot loop.